# QT / SQLite query placeholder does not work with WHERE clause

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I have a QT application that connects to a sqlite database. To build the queries I use the `prepare` and `bindValue` methods. I am able to get this working in an `INSERT` query. However these methods no longer work when the placeholder is in a `WHERE` clause.

```cpp
    QSqlQuery query(this->database);
    query.prepare("DELETE FROM `Shops` WHERE `id`=:id;");
    query.bindValue(":id", this->id);
    query.exec();

    qDebug() << query.executedQuery();
```

When I execute this code, the following line will be printed into the debug console:

```
"DELETE FROM `Shops` WHERE `id`=:id;"
```

I tried the same with an `UPDATE ... WHERE ...=:id` query and it didn't worked. In an `INSERT ... INTO ... VALUES (:name)` it worked however.

I already found out, that it is not possible to use placeholders for columns or table names in qt. But I could not found anything about restrictions with `WHERE` clauses. Does anyone has an idea?

*Ps: I know, that I could just concatenate the string. But I am curious, why it does not work.*

Comment: It might be cause of backquotes. I have a query similar to this. But it doesn't have backquotes and it works. Try without them. `"DELETE FROM Shops WHERE id=:id;"`

Comment: Already tried this. But didn't work :/ . I also tried to use positional placeholders, to change the placeholder name and to ad whitespaces around the placeholder